# Is is possible to transfer ownership of an Azure Key Vault to another person?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

We have an Azure-hosted SaaS solution, part of which creates keys for our customers stored in a Key Vault.  While they are using our solution, we own and manage the Key Vault they're using.  If a customer chooses to cancel their account with us, is there a way to transfer ownership of the key vault to them?  It can be a manual process - we hope to keep our customers.  But we would like ease their minds by making those secrets potentially available to them should they choose to cancel our service.

Comment: May i know if you want to move key vault from your subscription to client susbscription?

Comment: Yes, @RahulKumarShaw-MT, that's exactly right.  For as long as they are our customers, we would own and manage the keys, but if they choose to no longer use our software, we would like to transfer ownership of those keys to an account our customer owns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, you can transfer a key vault to a different tenant and subscription. I doubt the customer would want the Keyvault to remain in your subscription and tenant. Ofcourse this means that the customer needs to have an existing Azure subscription.

Please refer to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/move-subscription) on this.